# Pandas.DataFrame.join not working in my case

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

***Hey experts!***

I'm trying to load multiple files from list `ratios` and joining them in pandas one dataframe.

In `for loop`, code works fine in loading `csv` files but join function do not work and I get first data `(BCH-USD)` every time.

I checked everything and looks fine, 
later, I write to the same code without `for loop` and that code worked perfectly fine and joins the dataframe as expected. *(I added this code below)*

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 
import os 

data = pd.DataFrame()

ratios = ['BCH-USD','BTC-USD','ETH-USD','LTC-USD']
for ratio in ratios:
    cols = ['time','low','high','open','close','volume']
    path =  str(os.path.dirname (__file__) + f"/data/{ratio}.csv")
    df = pd.read_csv(path,names=cols)
    df.drop(['low','high','open'],axis=1,inplace=True)
    df.rename(columns={'close': f'{ratio}_close', 'volume': f'{ratio}_volume'},inplace=True)
    df.set_index('time',inplace=True)

    # print(df.head(1))

    if len(data) == 0:
        data = df
    elif (len(data) != 0):
        print(df.columns)
        data.join(df)

print(data)
```

> OUTPUT

```
Index(['BTC-USD_close', 'BTC-USD_volume'], dtype='object')
Index(['ETH-USD_close', 'ETH-USD_volume'], dtype='object')
Index(['LTC-USD_close', 'LTC-USD_volume'], dtype='object')
            BCH-USD_close  BCH-USD_volume
time
1528968660     871.719971        5.675361
1528968720     870.859985       26.856577
1528968780     870.099976        1.124300
1528968840     870.789978        1.749862
1528968900     870.000000        1.680500
...                   ...             ...
1535215020     531.479980        0.016868
...                   ...             ...
1535215020     531.479980        0.016868
1535215080     531.469971        0.013854
1535215140     531.479980        0.016900
1535215080     531.469971        0.013854
1535215140     531.479980        0.016900
1535215200     531.479980        0.299520
1535215260     531.630005        3.528913

[92225 rows x 2 columns]
```

***What I'm doing wrong?***

this is the code I tried later and worked as expected but without any loop.

```
df1 = pd.read_csv("./data/BCH-USD.csv", names=cols)

df1.rename(columns = {'close': 'bch_close', 'volume':'bch_volume'},inplace=True)

df1.set_index('time',inplace=True)

print(len(df1))
print(df1.head())




df2 = pd.read_csv("./data/btc-USD.csv", names=cols)

df2.rename(columns = {'close': 'btc_close', 'volume':'btc_volume'},inplace=True)

df2.set_index('time',inplace=True)

print(len(df1))
print(df1.head())

df1.join(df2[['btc_close','btc_volume']])
```

> OUTPUT

[image: Output]

Comment: try `data = df.copy()` instead as it will refrence the same df everytime

Comment: @ShubhamShaswat didn't get you!

Comment: the line where you have written `if len(data) == 0:
        data = df`replace it with `df.copy()` and check

Comment: didn't work @ShubhamShaswat